# How to view Cid image reference in html body section?

Tags: c#, html, sendmail, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using sendgrid inbound parse to converting emails to tickets in our system , in this case if user send mail with inline images then , send grid using cid references in image src tag as like below html code.

`"html": "<div dir=\"ltr\">Here's an email with multiple attachments<div><br></div><div><img src=\"cid:ii_1562e2169c132d83\" alt=\"Inline image 1\" width=\"455\" height=\"544\"><br clear=\"all\"><div><br></div>-- <br><div class=\"gmail_signature\" data-smartmail=\"gmail_signature\"><div dir=\"ltr\"><img src=\"https://sendgrid.com/brand/sg-logo-email.png\" width=\"96\" height=\"17\"><br><div><br></div></div></div></div></div>",`

if I pass this html value that to my html viewer then, it will show the blank image in viewer, so how can i include the the cid reference in html body section or any other ideas to view that image ?

[image]